Visual studio MAUI Project loses android emulator association at each startup
This issues appeared recently on my MAUI Project.
Previously, when I opened my MAUI Project in Debug Mode, here is what I saw :

Next to the RUN icon there was the device associated in the Device Manager.
Since I targetted my project to the Android 14 SDK (34), here is what I see :

I must to recreate, each time I'm starting Visual Studio, a new Android Device Emulator in order to run my project inside...
I tried to open the Device Manager to launch manually the previously created emulator but it looks like Visual Studio doesn't "see" it.
Is there somebody which knows the cause ?

Have you tried Repairing the Visual Studio from Visual Studio Installer or update to the latest version?

Since I :

Changed Project > General > Targeted platform from "x64" to "Any CPU"
Remove the "mac-catalyst" targetted platform from project file (text mode)
Connected my personnal account

The issue doesn't appears anymore.
I don't think Visuals Studio personnal account connection changed anything to my problem, but perhaps the project settings adjustments did the trick.
